# BigQuery - How to set the file stored in google cloud storage as schema file reference for BQ LOAD command?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have placed json schema file and json data file in a bucket(mybucket) and trying to load the data into BigQuery using bq load command as below and it fails,

```
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --schema=gs://mybucket/Schema.json myds.myTable gs://mybucket/sourcedata.json
```

**BigQuery error in load operation: Invalid value for: //MYBUCKET/SCHEMA.JSON is not a valid value**

But the command works when i set the schema file path to local file system

```
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --schema=D:\\json\\Schema.json myds.myTable gs://mybucket/sourcedata.json
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete commmand structure is

```
bq load [--source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON] [--project_id=your_project_id] destination_data_set.destination_table data_source_uri table_schema

bq load --project_id=my_project_bq dataset_name.bq_table_name gs://bucket_name/json_file_name.json path_to_schema_in_your_machine
```

Comment: `path_to_schema_in_your_machine` - Does it mean that I cannot set the path of schema file stored in google cloud storage?

Comment: Yes it means exactly that.